# Select records created between a time range regardless the date of creation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

I want to select a set of records created between 2 am to 3 am, regardless of the date it was created. Is there any way to achieve this?

Database: PostgreSQL

Comment: which database?

Comment: PostgreSQL database

Comment: @ShabiniRajadas I have added a possible solution to check time between 23 and 1 in my answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With PostgreSQL:

```
Model.where("created_at::time BETWEEN '14:00:00' AND '15:00:00'")
```

P.S. Before dealing with time queries make sure you are aware of the Rails default timezone (UTC) and issues connected to users' timezone differences.

Comment: Please add a comment/alarm mentioning UTC / `Time.zone` / local time problems. It worth it to add to _any_ question regarding times handling.

Comment: @mudasobwa agree, will do.

Comment: This works perfect. Thanks a ton. But just one clarification. Is there any possibility to check between 23:00:00 to 01:00:00. This always produces me an empty []

Comment: @ShabiniRajadas no. For this you'll have to change the way you query. I'll edit the answer

Comment: The second query don't work. Results are displayed when checking result from 20:00:00 to 23:00:00. But not from 20:00:00 to 01:00:00.

Comment: @AndreyDeineko, the first query in the answer works. But the second query don't work. So I split the query into two if the time range falls between two different dates, to select today's and the next day's data. I guess you can update the answer with only the first query. Thanks for all the help. Cheers :)

Comment: @ShabiniRajadas no probs. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [**`extract`**](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/functions-datetime.html#FUNCTIONS-DATETIME-EXTRACT) function in `PostgreSQL` to extract the time from date_time

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE extract(hour from created_at) BETWEEN 2 and 3;
```

> Is there any possibility to check between 23:00:00 to 01:00:00.

The same will not work with `time BETWEEN 23 and 1` but you can achieve it the following way:

```sql
SELECT * FROM users WHERE extract(hour from created_at) >= 23 and extract(hour from created_at) < 1;
```

Comment: is there any way to pass in minutes and seconds in the time?

Comment: `SELECT * FROM states WHERE updated_at::time BETWEEN '02:00:00' and '03:00:00';`

Comment: No luck deepak. This don't work for sceniors like 23:00:00 to 01:00:00

Comment: for that case `Between` doesn't work you need to compare them using  **`SELECT * FROM users WHERE created_at::time >= '23:00:00' and created_at::time < '01:00:00';`**

Comment: Thanks Deepak. but unfortunately that also don't work. So I split the query if it falls on two different dates. thanks for all your help. Cheers :)

Comment: Ohh.. my bad its not working because of `AND` try changing that to `Or`

Comment: Because 0 is not greater than 23 and less than 1 so it should be OR

Comment: No my friend. this breaks for some scenarios on the same day. :) thanks for the help.