# Trying to isolate the hours given a date range (YYYY:MM:DD HH:MM:SS) in SQL and group them. by specific hour intervals regardless of the date

Tags: postgresql

I am struggling trying to extract information out of the database I created in SQL.  The views work great and all data is displayed but I am trying to isolate the following:

1. Isolate time frames from 07:00:00 to 09:00:00.

Still new to coding, so help is appreciated.

```
SELECT ch.name,
       t.date,
       t.amount,
       t.card AS "Credit Card",
       t.id_merchant,
       m.name AS "Merchant",
       mc.name AS "merchant category"
FROM transaction AS t
   JOIN credit_card AS cc 
      ON (t.card = cc.card)
   JOIN card_holder AS ch
      ON (cc.cardholder_id = ch.id)
   JOIN merchant AS m
      ON (t.id_merchant = m.id
   JOIN merchant_category AS mc
      ON (m.id_merchant_category = mc.id);
```

Comment: What is the name of the table and the column, and what is the data type?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Select records created between a time range regardless the date of creation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40781467/select-records-created-between-a-time-range-regardless-the-date-of-creation)